# How to add index rules for Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I keep getting firebase messages on console regarding to add indexOn for user 4321 at chat rules. Below is my database.

[image]

And my rules in firebase is like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["name", "email","uid"],
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "chats": {
      "$key": {
        ".indexOn": ["uid"] 
      }
    }
   }
}
```

I'm not sure why the indexing not working. And how can I improve indexing for overall database?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Hi, a bit unrelated question. I'm dealing with a similar structure and I want to query the chats of an specific user. That should be `chats/CHAT_ID/USER_ID`, but because I don't have the CHAT_ID, I don't know how to handle that. Did you face similar problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your current data structure only allows to easily list all members of a chatroom, not the other way around. That may be the reason you get that message, because if you want to list all chats that user belongs to, you have to search through all `/chats` records.

You probably need to duplicate the chat room membership data both at `/chat/<chat-id>/members` and `/users/<uid>/groups`. Your case is almost identical to the one in [the Firebase guide here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout) -- read particularly the description below code in the section linked, but it's best to read the whole guide, it really helped me to understand how the database works.

Btw: your rule in chats: `".indexOn": ["uid"]` doesn't do anything with the sample data you posted. It says to "index chat rooms by their `uid` attribute", but your chat rooms don't have an `uid` key inside (meaning `uid: 'someid'`, not `'someid': true`). See the [indexing guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) on more info how indexing works.

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of indexing `orderByValue:` and `orderByChild`

**Indexing with orderByValue::**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "scores": {
      ".indexOn": ".value"
    }
  }
}
```

***JSON Tree***

```
{
  "employee": {
    <"employee1Key">: {
      "empName": Rohit Sharma,
      "Designation": SW Developer,
      "empId": EMP776,
      "branchDetails": {
        "branch": Software,
        branchLocation: Pune,
        branchId: BR556
      }
    },
    <"employee2Key>": {
      "empName": Vira tKholi,
      "Designation": Accountant,
      "empId": EMP908,
      "branchDetails": {
        "branch": Finance,
        branchLocation: Dheli,
        branchId: BR557
      }
    },
    <"employee3Key">: {
      "empName": MS Dhoni,
      "Designation": Sales Manager,
      "empId": EMP909,
      "branchDetails": {
        "branch": Sales and Marketing,
        branchLocation: Pune,
        branchId: BR556
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Indexing with orderByChild:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "employee": {
      ".indexOn": ["empName", "empId", "designation"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Multilevel Indexing:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "employee": {
      ".indexOn": ["empName","empId","branchDetails/branch",
        "branchDetails/branchLocation","branchDetails/branchId"]
    }
  }
}
```

You can also refer to this link for the Firebase Real-Time Database Data Indexing.

[Firebase Real-Time Database Data Indexing](https://medium.com/@kodagvikram/firebase-real-time-database-indexing-83f16e7adf9a?source=friends_link&sk=dbc8a619b98b4a331a0f6caae9bdbdc2)

Comment: Provide context for links: *Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*

Comment: Thank for your suggestion!!